# Can we get records from firebase in pdf or excel

Tags: ios, database, firebase

We have an ios app which uses firebase as database. We don't have configure server for the application. We are inserting, updating and getting data (records) from firebase storage (behaves like server). My requirement is i need to get one week records in excel or pdf format and send the file over email. Can we automate this process once in every week. Is there any possibility to execute some scripts in firebase console to automate this process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is asking multiple questions. In the future, try to stick to one per post as multiple questions can make answers very long and convoluted.

> 1) My requirement is i need to get one week records in excel or pdf
>   format

No, firebase does not have that as a direct option. Firebase is a JSON database and exporting (from the Real Time Data Base) will be json formatted text.

It's pretty straightforward get the data you want via a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for the Real Time Database or [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for Firestore and then export it from your app into whatever format you like.

Note that Excel, Numbers.app, OpenOffice, other processing apps etc can read comma delimited files easily so that may be an option instead of creating a specific filetype. There are also a number of JSON 'converters' as well.

Lastly, Firestore exporting is supported through their [managed export options](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import) which would enable data to be exported to BigQuery for example.

> 2) Can we automate this process once in every week.

Yes you can automate tasks to occur on a regular basis via a cron job and Firebase [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

There's a great Firebase Blog on [Scheduling Cloud Functions for Firebase (cron)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html) as well as additional reading in the Firebase Guide [Schedule Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

and for reference here's information about [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check all the links